# Phonegap não muda o package name

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou usando o *Phonegap build* para gerar o APK.

Porém ao enviar para a Play Store ele fala que o nome do aplicativo é "com.phonegap.ww".

Abri o APK com o APK Editor e realmente ele aparece este nome, porém já alterei o `config.xml`, o `androidmanifest.xml`, e não tem jeito do APK ser gerado com o novo nome.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: print do apk editor]

Answer (score 1):

Quando criou o projeto poderia ter passado como parâmetro o nome completo do pacote.

Segue uma lista dos arquivos que possivelmente se alterar o nome do pacote pode ser que resolva o problema. Principalmente os da pasta Ant-Build.

- `\config.xml`
- `\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml`
- `\platforms\android\ant-build\AndroidManifest.cordova.xml`
- `\platforms\android\ant-build\proguard.txt`
- `\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml`
- `\platforms\firefoxos\config.xml`

Outra opção pode ser criar um novo projeto com mesmo nome e com o caminho do pacote que deseja.

Ex.: `cordova create Projeto1 br.com.exemplo.projeto1 Projeto1`

Depois copiar os arquivos da pasta `www` do seu projeto atual para a nova pasta `www` do projeto novo.